# Usage report in WSS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have enabled the usage report in wss but I am only seeing a folder in the 12 Hive LOGS folder but no log files in it.

Let me know

Thanks
RHM

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled all of the features required? Follow all the steps in this [Configure Usage Reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541%28office.12%29.aspx) link from Microsoft?

There are a number of steps that need to be completed. Also, I'm not sure why you are looking for the usage reports in the 12-hive. You should be able to access them from the UI.

[Edit]: In the process of responding to your comment I found [this TechNet link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/34f2ced0-d1b2-4a9a-bc0c-cd0a3512d4c1/). It describes exactly what you are trying to do with Usage Reporting.

Good luck (:

Comment: I cannot find SSP in WSS ?